# Model file, and DB interaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a model file, such as

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
    firstname   : {type: String, required: false},
    lastname    : {type: String, required: false},
    email       : {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

I want to create functions to update, save or delete a user from the database.

Where should I be putting such DB-related functions?
I was thinking in the route files, but also in the model.js file itself, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

In the same file, certainly. Think of `model.js` as an interface that has convenience methods that allow you to work with DB.
It's sole purpose is to define schema, add some helpers (if necessary) and expose a **one** model (it's important) to the outside world.

Read more about mongoose [methods and statics](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). This might be helpful.

Also it's wise to name the file that defines model after the model itself. `user.js` in your case.